# Phonegap/Cordova Media Class Permissions

Tags: android, cordova

I am making an Android Phonegap/Cordova app which uses the Media Class found here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_media_media.md.html

It says that the Media class requires the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

When I add these permissions to my app/AndroidManifest.xml file the audio and app works perfect. If I remove all the permissions the app still works perfect on my Android device. My question is has Phonegap changed the required permissions? Are any permissions required for a Phonegap app to work on all devices? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which version of phonegap are you using? with phonegap 3.x the permissions are automatically added by the plugin.

Permission are not specific to phonegap but are relative to android. When you set permissions in androidmanifest.xml, when a user installs an app, he will be notified of the required permissions and if you do not require the permissions, there are some operations your app will not be able to perform.

You can use the media plugin without requiring the permissions, it will work fine as long as you do not try to perform operations that require permissions : you will be able to play audio but not to record.

Comment: I have the latest phonegap which comes with the command line interface I think 3.3. I removed the permissions that the plugin added automatically because all I need is the ability to play back audio and it works fine.